# Installing PG_SIMILARITY on PostgreSQL, Windows

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install the pg_similarity extension for Windows PostgreSQL 9.1 x64.

I believe I have placed the necessary files into the `/share/contrib` directory and also the `/share/extension` directory as instructed in the documentation.

When running `CREATE EXTENSION pg_similarity;` I get this error:

`ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_similarity": No such file or directory`

I believe this is because I do not have the `pg_similarity.dll` file in the `/lib/` directory.

The instructions at https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity (for Windows) say to generate that file by "executing `pg_config --libdir`" which obviously does not work in and of itself. I assume other steps are implied or left out.

Could someone please explain how to complete that part of the installation and/or generate the needed .dll file and provide it? The installation instructions for Windows are not very detailed.

The only other part of the instructions I did not follow was:
`"Edit contrib/Makefile and add pg_similarity to SUBDIRS variable;"` however that file already contains a line `subdir = contrib/pg_similarity` which sounds as though that has already been set. If not I certainly don't know what needs to be changed and that's all there is to the explanation of what to change.

Comment: Most extension publishers have no interest in Windows and do not bother to support it or even know how to. If they support Windows, it's usually only via MinGW. If you wish to use the extension on Windows you'll probably need to compile it yourself. I wrote some generic instructions [here](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) but you'll want some C programming experience or it'll be quite a learning curve. MinGW-based compilation might be easier, haven't really tried.

Comment: Added a note on the tracker too: https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity/issues/10

Comment: I think you misunderstood the installation instructions. You have to compile (but not install) PostgreSQL with MSVC and then pg_similarity. It will generate the pg_similarity.dll that can be copied to lib directory.

Comment: If you were to compile it would I be able to just copy the dll file into that folder? It's not something I know enough about to be able to do without instructions from ground zero